# jQuery and Z-Indexes Reset

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have 5 div boxes that each have a z-index score.

div1 - z-index: 0

div2 - z-index: -1

div3 - z-index: -2

div4 - z-index: -3

div5 - z-index: -4

div6 - z-index: -5

I want to use jQuery to change the z indexes on click. So for instance:

```
$("#div2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index","0");
    $("#div3").css("z-index","-2");
    $("#div4").css("z-index","-3");
    $("#div5").css("z-index","-4");
    $("#div6").css("z-index","-5");

    $("#div2").css("z-index","1");

});
```

This would obviously bring my div2 box in front of all of the other boxes.

Now if I want to go to another box I have to do the following:

```
$("#div3").click(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index","0");
    $("#div2").css("z-index","-1");
    $("#div4").css("z-index","-2");
    $("#div5").css("z-index","-4");
    $("#div6").css("z-index","-5");

    $("#div3").css("z-index","1");

});
```

I have to define the original values and then redefine the box I want listed highest. Is there a way to reset them back to their first values so all hopefully I can avoid some of the reseting? I would like it to hopefully look something like this:

```
$("#div3").click(function () {
    $("div").css("original css z-index values");

    $("#div3").css("z-index","1");

});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use $.data to save the first initial values , and each reset to set the values from $.data.

p.s.

i dont understand why you put -1 , -2 etc...

you should have one layer up and all other layers - with low number ( can be the same)

so put some class all over the divs ("lowZ" class)  which defines : z-index:0

and put active class ("highZ")for active layer with : z-index:999

and then each time do:

```
$(".divClass").removeClass("highZ");
$("#div2").addClass("highZ");
```

Comment: The reason there are different z-index (-1,-2, etc) is because the div boxes are collaged around the page. So it looks like a stack of magazines on a coffee table with some above the others.

Comment: p.s. you can also multple / divide by (-10) each one which you want to make active. so if you want  div 2 : so it has -2 * -10 = 20  { the highest} ... and if you want to reset it so 20/(-10)=-2 // back to original state. - this way you dont have to touch all the others.